# IOS Encryption library recommend

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

Considering encrypt password,is there any safe IOS encryption libaray or apple technology  to recommand?Thanks!

Comment: You could probably get this reopened by rewriting to focus on the best practice for storing passwords instead of asking for a library recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

For storing passwords, you should almost certainly be using Apple's [keychain API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychains). Storing the password in the keychain lets it be synched to the user's other devices, and it puts the burden of keeping the password secure on Apple instead of your app.